# Creating one PHP array from two sql tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not the best at writing complicated (for me) mysqli queries.

I am trying to create one array using data from two different tables.

TABLE 1: text_strings

```
id    string
1     hello
2     good_morning
```

TABLE 2: text_translations

```
id    textid    lang    translation
1     1         en      Hello
2     1         es      Hola
3     2         en      Good Morning
4     2         es      Buenos Dias
```

So, I am trying to make an array of translations based on the language. If my language is set to Spanish (es), the array would be like:

```
['hello'=>'Hola','good_morning'=>'Buenos Dias']
```

So, the structure of the array would be:

```
$lang['string'] = ['translation'];
```

In written English, if language is "es", select all from "text_translations" where lang is "es" and make the array key equal the value of the textid string value in the "text_strings" table.

I'm assuming something with `LEFT JOIN`, but I really don't know how to set up this query.

Comment: this might give you a hint in which `JOIN` to use: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: `$lang[$id]['translation'];` would be better practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats pretty simple JOIN. Fetch this query from db to array.

```
SELECT t.translation, s.string
FROM text_strings AS s
JOIN text_translations AS t ON s.id = t.textid AND lang = 'es'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will get you two columns associated with each other, `string` and `translation`, and over PHP you can fetch it, and create an array as required, (string in place of key and translation in place of value).

I had used `INNER JOIN` cause, both the `string` and `translation` should be there, in case if any one of them not found. That will be excluded.

```
SELECT TextString.`string`, TextTranslation.`translation` FROM text_strings TextString INNER JOIN text_translations TextTranslation 
ON TextString.id = TextTranslation.text_id
WHERE TextTranslation.lang = 'en'
```

and over PHP, you can do it like:

```
$translations = array();
while ($strings = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $translations[$strings['string']] = $strings['translation'];
}
```

Comment: Do I pull it like `while ($strings = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`?

Comment: Thank you, but I am using it exactly as you show, but I am getting "fetch_array is non-object" error. `$query = $db->query("SELECT string FROM text_strings TextString INNER JOIN text_translations TextTranslation ON TextString.id = TextTranslation.text_id WHERE TextTranslation.lang = '$lang'");`

Comment: I guess `$db` is not mysqli object, Apart form that everything seems well. Also please look at [mysqli query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your question is more "how to join two tables". I advise you figure that out before worrying about how to handle them in php. W3 schools has a really simple and straightforward rundown of sql. The section on joins can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).